# C# Return substring starting from position past the end of string

Tags: c#, for-loop, substring, indexof

I am trying to trim a string into a number of substrings according to the user input.
For example in `Console ARG1 = 'DATABASE' ARG2 = '3,2,3'`
The method will translate DATABASE into newList (DAT,AB,ASE)

The code I am currently working on is

```
        string[] sizeSplit = ARG3.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            string eachNumber = sizeSplit[i];
            int j = Int32.Parse(eachNumber);


            string splitString = pattern.Substring(0,j);

            seperatedWord.Add(splitString);
        }
```

But this only works for the first substring, as the second and following will need to be substring with the index of (pastPosition, j). as I stated in the title.

Could anyone point me out the way of doing this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep track the position

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeSplit.Length; i++)
{
     string eachNumber = sizeSplit[i];
     int j = Int32.Parse(eachNumber);         
     string splitString = pattern.Substring(index,j);
     index += j;
     seperatedWord.Add(splitString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

ADD new Variable Previous. It have the starting index of sub string

```
string ARG1  = "DATABASE"; string ARG2 = "3,2,3";
int previous = 0;
string[] sizeSplit = ARG2.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < sizeSplit.Length; i++)
{
    string eachNumber = sizeSplit[i];
    int j = Int32.Parse(eachNumber);

    string splitString = ARG1.Substring(previous, j);
    previous +=j;
    seperatedWord.Add(splitString);
}
```